# Creating json patch with a variable created during azure pipeline runtime

Tags: bash, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am setting up the ability to deploy test environments under different kubernetes namespaces. I am running this script in my azure-pipeline with the hope of setting the ingress controller host for the deploy.

```
- script: |
              sanitized_namespace="$(echo "$(Build.SourceBranchName)" | sed -r 's/[^a-z0-9-]//g')"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sanitized_namespace]$sanitized_namespace"   
              echo '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/rules/0/host", "value": "'"$sanitized_namespace"'"}]' > host-patch.json   
              cat ./host-patch.json   
            name: namespace   
            displayName: 'Remove invalid characters for test namespace'
```

However, every time I run this or variations of this the created ./host-patch.json file has an empty string for "value" rather than the value of my variable sanitized_namespace. I know the variable for sanitized namespace is not empty because I use it elsewhere in the same job and it works as expected.

Can anyone else tell me how I might create this json file to patch the ingress host with this variable.

In the grand scheme of things I would like to set it to be something like this

```
echo '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/rules/0/host", "value": "'"$sanitized_namespace.somedomain.com"'"}]' > host-patch.json
```

Comment: I have also attempted creating the ./host-patch.json file upfront and editing the value in associated with the key. Like this.

sed -i "s|test2.somedomain.com|${sanitized_namespace}.somedomain.com|g" ./host-patch.json

Comment: So I learned that there is something about an agent working directory when using sed in azure pipeline. I also learned that sed does not modify the file just outputs the changes. So I modified the command to sed "s|test2.somedomain.com|${sanitized_namespace}.somedomain.com|g" .full/path/host-patch.json > .full/path/modified.json